# get all data from store like raw in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to get all the data from the store in order to replace some variables there, is it possible to do this?

[image]

Comment: yes it's possible, all data in redux are accessible and can be updated via `reducer`

Comment: make reducers but try to make your changes as small as possible and avoid modifying the whole store at once